# How to remove all special characters except numbers and space in a string using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm developing a Phonegap Android application. Now I want to pass some parameters from one page to another html page. I'm not using any server side methods. In the second page I want to get all passed parameters from first page using JavaScript.

For example here is an URL:

> file:///C:/Users/dell/Projects/testapp1/search_result.html?searchstr=word1+*%26^+word2+3+word3+%40%23&city=city&showdishesnearby=false

The below function used to extract each parameters values:

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
        function (m, key, value) {
            vars[key] = value;
        });
    return vars;
}

searchString = getUrlVars()["searchstr"]; // this is how I call above function to get value of passed particular parameter
```

Now I want to remove all special characters except numbers and white space in variable `searchString`.

I have used the below code:

```
searchString = searchString.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, " ");
```

but that doesn't solve my problem. How to remove all special characters except numbers and space in a string using JavaScript?

Comment: `str.replace(/[^\d\s]+/, '').replace(/\s{2,}/, ' ')`

Comment: Sorry Mr.falsetru your solution also didn't work for me. Please check the question, i have given more explanation about the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
searchString.replace(/[^a-z\d\s]+/gi, "");
```

removes all but letters, numbers and whitespace.

```
var s = 'keep%8$this part 3£$@plz £$% @£';
s.replace(/[^a-z\d\s]+/gi, "");
// "keep8this part 3plz  "
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add below code to replace all alpha-numeric character(punctuation, pace, underscore)

```
var string = str.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g,"")
```